# Почему php-fpm + nginx не работает без файла index.php в контейнере nginx?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Вся суть в том, что есть некий, проксирующий запрос в контейнер с fpm, nginx контейнер

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root        /var/www/html/public;
    index       index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass api:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

и php-fpm с laravel/lumen на борту.
При запуске контейнеров без монтирования каталога public в nginx показывает текст "File not found.", но стоит смонтировать в nginx хотя бы только public/index.php как сразу всё начинает работать.

Согласен, что public со статикой нужен в nginx, но можно ли сделать так, чтобы он работал без монтирования каких-либо файлов? (т.к. приложение является json-api источником и в обработке статики не нуждается)

Comment: Прочитать документацию по try_files и подумать зачем оно тут

Comment: Пробовал убирать, начинает отвечать 404 с текстом "File not found."

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#proxy-everything

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил следующим образом:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/html/public;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass api:9000;
    }
}
```

```yml
version: "3"

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./images/Api.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./api:/var/www/html

  proxy:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./hosts:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - api
```

Хотелось бы заметить, что я пробовал по разному хитро конфигурировать проксирование, но я заметил, что `File not found.` будет выпадать в любом случае, если не указать параметры `root` и `index`
Теперь любой path будет обрабатываться через fpm.

Но на любой запрос с .php на конце будет даваться ответ "Файл не найден", но думаю это не значительная проблема т.к. приложение обрабатывает идентификаторы ресурсов через единую точку входа, а статических .php у нас не существует.